# How to I make a plane wrap around and object?

Tags: modeling, texturing, texture-painting

I don't want to fiddle with unwrapping and adding a texture, I just want to add spots to my guy's head. I feel like the easiest was to do that would be to create circles and just place them but how would I get those flat circles to form to the contours of his head?

[image]

[image]

Comment: this should help you get what you want: https://youtu.be/j4WMbr0_qIA?si=c9SGC4rhEcb-TAzT

Comment: Just hitting `U` > _Smart UV Project_, then creating a new completely red texture and making some white dots on it with a brush set to a hard falloff seems very easy to me. At least easier then fidlling around with placing circles on the mesh or using _Geometry Nodes_... the tutorial is about evenly sized and distributed dots on a sphere anyway, for more random placement and varying size on a different mesh than a sphere the nodetree has to be changed as well. Your question says you don't want to use UVs and textures, but the tags say this is about `texturing` and `texture-painting`?

Comment: The title of this question is misleading, isn't it? Where in this example do you wrap a plane around an object? You want to have a procedural texture that creates round dots on a sphere, don't you?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my post. I've really only just begun and I'm maybe not articulating as well as I could. What I mean to say is imagine placing 12 circular sticker across the head of the plant, evenly and deliberately spaced. I wouldn't mind using geometry nodes if I knew how since that seems very possible. Using the shrinkwrap modifier gets me very close but I must be doing something wrong since my circle distorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much everyone for your wonderful help! I was able to figure it out doing the following:

- Added circle, filled with triangular faces, and used knife tool to further subdivided (I'm sure there's an easier was to do that but idk how)
- added a shrink wrap modifier to the circle with the targe being the head
- changed wrap method to project > on surface, offset to -1

Then I was able to literally lie the circles on the mesh like sticker (though I did need to rotate them into an approximate position before hand.)

[image]

With a bit of tweaking, it came out perfect.

Thank you again for the suggestions and being so helpful!

Answer (score 7):

You could do it procedurally with a *Voronoi Texture*, make sure that its *Randomness* value is low, plug into a red and white *ColorRamp*, put the *ColorRamp* needles close to each other to have sharp contours:

[image]

Other solution, with an *Image Texture*, unwrap your object with the *Smart UV Project* option, give it a material with an *Image Texture* that is red, switch to *Texture Paint* mode, in the *Tool* panel choose a white color:

[image]

To paint sharp dots, put the brush *Strength* at 1, under *Falloff* choose the square shape:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Yep, that's the best and easiest way I'd say. Had no time to prepare an answer myself. Just thought I don't get what would be so difficult doing it with textures (either image or like you with Voronoi) that one would want to "wrap a mesh around an object" instead.

Comment: I guess it's because when you begin you're not familiar with materials

Comment: Lmao, very excellent deduction @moonboots

Comment: This was a fantastic suggestion and got me very, very close. Thank you so much :) But I don't seem to have the control I need. I want to duplicate the design of the toy with 12 dots of mostly the same size spread evenly over the head. I've played with the location and scale but it still doesn't give me the desired effect. Thank you again for taking the time to help me though! :

Comment: In that case give as many precisions as possible, what do you mean by "duplicate the design of the toy"? you could also unwrap with the Smart UV Project option and paint red spots

Comment: I've edited my answer, another solution is to paint onto the surface in Texture Paint mode

Comment: @moonboots No worries! I was able to get it working with the shrinkwrap modifier! :)