# Turning hairs into texture-spots?

Tags: texturing, shaders, hair

Just came across [How to I make a plane wrap around and object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309889/how-to-i-make-a-plane-wrap-around-and-object) which asks about adding spots to a character model. One solution suggested a Voroni texture, which is probably the "correct" easy way to go.

However, it got me thinking about a different solution that seems like it should be feasible. If I wanted to add spots to a model (Sue's head will serve as an examplar), but I want to be able to control the size and position by placing hairs at the center of the spots and making them longer/shorter to adjust the size, is there a way to achieve that?

Essentially, for each fragment, I want to select the nearest hair, then apply a ramp scaled by some constant times the length of that hair. (Producing a Voroni from the set of hair points is a good start, but the shader also needs to know the length of the hair associated with the fragment's cell.)

For bonus points, the shader would compute the minimum of the scaled distance to *all* hairs, but we can assume that isn't necessary.